# SwiftUI iOS app experiencing graphical glitches when using indices in ForEach loop instead of elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing an iOS app using SwiftUI, and I'm experiencing graphical glitches when I use the indices of my state array in a ForEach loop instead of the elements themselves. Specifically, the UI elements in my list start to flicker and disappear when I attempt to reorder them.

[image: List Graphical Glitch]

*The 'Directions' section is animated correctly, while the 'Ingredients' section appears glitchy.*

#### Approximation of the 'Add Recipe' view

The only difference between these two sections is that one `ForEach` iterates over the arrays indices, while the other iterates over the elements.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var testData = ["Test 1", "Test 2"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section("Ingredients") {
                    ForEach(testData.indices, id: \.self) {
                        Text(testData[$0])
                    }
                    .onMove {
                        testData.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                    }
                }
                
                Section("Directions") {
                    ForEach(testData, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                    .onMove {
                        testData.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?</strike> Does anyone know the "why"? What are the SwiftUI mechanics behind this graphical hiccup?

Comment: i think you know the problem already ;-)

Comment: @malhal Haha well yes, I suppose I do know the problem. I'd like to understand the SwiftUI mechanics behind it. To me, it seems that these two code snippets should yield the same result.

Comment: read the docs for ForEach, id cannot be self needs to be a unique property

Comment: @malhal `self` is a unique property. Also, Daniel isn't having a problem with the code that uses `self`. His question was about the code that uses `indices`.

Comment: @Adam no, his data is dynamic state, not a let so can't use self, must use a stable identifier property. If he learns that then he won't even try to use indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI determines what Views to redraw and animate based on their identity. Ultimately, it creates a representation of the current hierarchy with IDs, then applies transformations, then compares the new representation with the old representation. It uses the changes to determine what to animate.

When you use indexes as the identity, you tie identity to current location, rather than to the value itself. So moving items around creates inconsistent situations.

Consider the list identified by unique values: `A B C D`. Applying the operation "move item 2 to position 0". This should result in `C A B D`, and it does, and that is correct.

But now consider the list identified by index: `0 1 2 3`. Now apply "move item 2 to position 0." The new list is *still* `0 1 2 3`, since the identity is the **current** location, and changes when the item is moved. This breaks the precondition that the end-state should be consistent with the operations, and can glitch the UI. Whether it actually glitches the UI depends on the both the specific setup and implementation details of SwiftUI. It's undefined behavior, so all kinds of things can happen.

You very rarely should use indexes as identifiers, and if you must, then you cannot reorder the list.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. Swift has to recreate the list since the indices associated with the moved items change, which adds steps to the UI update, so the animation doesn't render smoothly.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Totally makes sense. After reading the second paragraph, I had my facepalm "no duh" moment. Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` does not need your array's indices for iteration. There is no reason to pass them into your `ForEach` loop, especially since you are using `\.self` to identify the array items. The solution is clear from your question: Remove the `.indices` portion of your code and use `$0` instead of `testData[$0]`. It will run just fine, and you won't have the graphical glitch.

Comment: I removed above from the code for the sake of simplicity, but the reason I was using indices was to control `FocusState` and update the items in the array by index. I will rework to use the elements to avoid the graphical glitch; however, I am still curious about the cause of the graphical glitch. I assume it is related in some way to the identity of the views, however, the indices be unique (unless I am misunderstanding something about swiftui identity).

Comment: Indices are unique, but they are not strongly tied to the element. For example, if item A is at 0 and B is at 1, if they switch places, the indices may be unique, but the data they are tied to is certainly not.